# Import selected column from excel files

Tags: excel

I have excel files , I want to import selected columns from them and append in one file .
The columns I want to import is present in all files but not in the same column letter.so I cannot use power query to combine files .

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and show us what have you done so far and explain what part of your code is not working. It also helps if you can show a sample data and how you expect the output to be like from the sample data. Reading [ask] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: Probably you need an VBA macro for this.